# $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B) $ implies $A$ and $B$ are measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

In the proof, it says that for disjoint $A$ and $B$, $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B) \implies A$ and $B$ are measurable.

The caratheodory definition of measurable set is that for some $A$, if $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cup B) + m^*(A \setminus B)$,  then $B$ is measurable. But I can't see the relation between these two. Could you explain this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I ask what book this is from?

Comment: Sure. It is from chapter 2.6 of part 1 in Royden.

Comment: Note that Caratheodory requires that equality to hold for **all** $A$ for $B$ to be measurable — if you only needed **some** set then $A=B$ would imply all sets are measurable.

Comment: Also, your statement of Caratheodory is off. You want $m^*(A\cap B)$ instead of $m^*(A\cup B)$.

Comment: Notice the **for every** part. It never said in the proof that $m^∗(A∪B)=m^∗(A)+m^∗(B)\implies A,B$ measurable. It rather says $((∀A,B⊆\mathbb R)\ A∩B=∅ \implies m^∗(A∪B)=m^∗(A)+m^∗(B))⟹((∀C⊆\mathbb R)\ C$ is measurable$).$

Comment: You also have a quantifier issue in your definition of measurable. A set $B$ is measurable if, for every $A$, $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \setminus B)$.  It does not say that $B$ is measurable if that identity only holds for some $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **every** pair of disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, assume the following holds:

> $m^*(A\cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B).$

Now, let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets. Then $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)$ where $A\cap B$ is disjoint from $A\setminus B$.

By our assumption, this means that $m^*(A) = m^*(A\cap B) + m^*(A\setminus B)$, and so by Caratheodory we have that $B$ is measurable since $A$ was arbitrary. Unfortunately, out choice of $B$ was **also** arbitrary, so every set is measurable!

Comment: You really should say "for every" in the first sentence. Otherwise, it could equally well be read as "for some".  This is particularly relevant when the OP has such obvious issues with quantifiers.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thanks for the heads up. I haven’t heard that “for any” can be interpreted as “for some” — that could be bad!

Answer (score 0):

That holds.
You get to be so careful about where outer measure is defined on.
We start with a measurable space (X,F) and let Γ be an outer measure on (X,F) and let μ be an measure on it.
Let's go through what we've learned.

Γ: 2^X→[0,+∞] holds
Γ(∪i E_i) ≦ ΣiΓ(E_i) (subadditivity) as for E_i∈F i=1,2,..., regardless of whether E_i and E_i' (i≠i') are disjoint or not.

μ: F→[0,+∞] holds:
μ(∪i E_i) = ΣiΓ(E_i) (σ-additivity) as for E_i∈F i=1,2,..., obly E_i and E_i' (i≠i') are disjoint.

There are a lot of constructions on measure, but one defines measure μ as a restriction of outer measure Γ from 2^X to F. As we already see Γ has subadditivity, but measure μ which is a restriction of outer measure Γ has σ-additivity. So as long as an outer measure Γ holds finite additivity and we pick up disjoint sets E_i and E_i' (i≠i') in F, E_i and E_i' are measurable.

Sorry for being illegible since I am a newbie here.

Comment: A [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Cheers.